# Solr Facet list empty when there are documents found

Tags: solr, faceted-search, facet

I'm experiencing an issue regarding Solr facets. I have configured my schema.xml so I have two fields (**STRASSE_s** and **facet_strasse**, as well as copyfield, since the **STRASSE_s** field, being of type *text* gets processed and those processed facets results are returned (chopped, splitted strings)):

```
<field name="STRASSE_s" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="facet_strasse" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false" />

<copyfield source="STRASSE_s" dest="facet_strasse" />
```

I want to create a Solr query, to get all different addresses, matching certain pattern.  I tried to achieve that with request below (all addresses containing 'dis'). I'm using *facet_strasse* as a facet field to get entire text, not the one being chopped and splitted by Solr.

```
http://localhost:9001/solr/my_core/select?q=STRASSE_s%3Adis*&rows=0&facet=true&facet.field=facet_strasse&facet.limit=10&wt=json&indent=true
```

The result I receive is that there are certain addresses, but I don't get the list of facets (empty)!
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdZiZ.png)

On the other hand, if I use *STRASSE_s* as a facet field, I do get the collection of the facets as [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpsoQ.png)

Can you tell me what am I missing and how can I achieve to get actual list of facets, with entire street text?

[EDIT] My guess is that copyfield function isn't performed correctly, since there seems to be no values in destination field (*facet_strasse*), but not sure why.

Thanks,
Lazar

Comment: I tried the suggested approach with multi-value field, but it doesn't solve the issue. I guess that since **STRASSE_s** is not multivalue field, it isn't needed to define copyfield destination (**facet_strasse**) to be multivalued neither, as it has only 1 value for a specific document.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is with facet_strasse field definition, set the multi-valued to true in facet_strasse then issue would be resolved :)

```
<field name="facet_strasse" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
```

Read more about copy field on [solr wiki copy field](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Copying+Fields).